# How to commit bundle files (that are really directories) as binaries into Git

Tags: git

There are bundle files on macOS that are really directories but are treated as single files by their corresponding applications (e.g. a `.app` or an iPhoto library). Is there way to commit them to a git repo as a single binary file? Would that even make sense? I tried marking them as binaries in `.gitattributes` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1):

> - A *package* is any directory that the Finder presents to the user as if it were a single file.
> - A *bundle* is a directory with a standardized hierarchical structure that holds executable code and the resources used by that code.

and

> The Finder considers a directory to be a package if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> 1. The directory has a known filename extension: .app, .bundle,
>    .framework, .plugin, .kext, and so on.
> 2. The directory has an extension
>    that some other application claims represents a package type; see
>    Document Packages.
> 3. The directory has its package bit set.

This suggests that in Git, it really is just a directory with a specific set of subdirectories and files. A bundle *isn't* a special file, just a directory that the Finder treats specially.

Comment: I know it's a directory. My question was if it's possible to make git treat it like a file, similar what a tarball is.

Comment: A tarball *is* a file. You can't make Git treat it a bundle as a file, and to answer your "Would that even make sense?", I'd would answer "no".

Comment: I know that a tarball is a file. You seem to be treating this as a theoretical question about git while I have a problem and I'm looking for solutions. I think one way is to do something similar to `https://github.com/ckrf/xlsx-git`, i.e. use pre/post hooks and convert the bundle to a tarball

Comment: What problem does treating a directory as a directory pose? Only the Finder treats a bundle specially: try something like `cp /System/Applications/TextEdit.app .`.